# Can not figure out minimal interfaces needing to implement in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to understand what is the minimal number of interfaces necessary that need to be implemented in ASP.NET Identity.

I know that you must implement IUser, IUserStore but I'm not sure beyond that.

I've looked at this post: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Simple-Aspnet-Identiy-Core-7475a961/sourcecode?fileId=105973&pathId=287897708 and it seems that the UserManager is there but I don't think it's a required interface (not sure).

My question is, what is the absolute minimal interface implementation to have a functioning asp.net identity configuration working.

Also, I think it is the same in asp.net core as the previous version of asp.net.  True?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on which version that your implementing and what you want to do.
For example, if you are using Identity 3 (ASP.NET Core) and you for example want to implement support for another database then you need to minimally implement a custom userstore and, optionally, a custom rolestore.

The interfaces you implement for those are (only need to implement what you need) as follows. And in those classes, the database related code is inserted.

Userstore:

```
        IUserStore<TUser>,
        IUserLoginStore<TUser>,
        IUserRoleStore<TUser>,
        IUserClaimStore<TUser>,
        IUserPasswordStore<TUser>,
        IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser>,
        IUserEmailStore<TUser>,
        IUserLockoutStore<TUser>,
        IQueryableUserStore<TUser>,
        IUserTwoFactorStore<TUser>,
        IUserAuthenticationTokenStore<TUser>,
        IUserPhoneNumberStore<TUser>
```

And for the RoleStore:

```
        IQueryableRoleStore<TRole>,
        IRoleClaimStore<TRole>
```

And then you can either use the built in IdentityEntity classes (IdentityUser, IdentityRole and so forth) or use you own entity classes (no interfaces needed for those if you create your own store).

```
    .services.AddIdentity<YourUser, YourRole>()
    .AddUserStore<YourUserStore>()
    .AddRoleStore<YourRoleStore>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

If you ONLY want some extra properties on the classes then just extend IdentityUser and IdentityRole and add the properties you need. (this is the same in v2 / non core unless my memory fails me ;) ). Difference is that in v2 You can implement IUser, in v3 / core you need to extend IdentityUser if you want to use the default stores.

If you want to use the absolute defult then you do not have to implement anything. Primarily just add it in your startup.cs file.

```
        .services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EntityDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

But as i said initially, depends on what you want to accomplish and which version your using :).

Comment: Version 2.2 of identity.  Specifically I'm wanting to know the minimum implementation to be called asp.net identity.  I'm building a course and I'm trying to define what is asp.net identity.

Comment: Ah i see, sorry misunderstood you at first. I would not venture to say exactly what the absolute minimal implementation is other than starting stripping things down.

I think your close in regards to your interfaces (perhaps needing the IUserLoginStore as well for the authentication), but perhaps someone can give you a better answer on this matter :)